# how to skip the stage if my build stage fails in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using three stages here , In this if my second stage **Build** fails it should skip the third stage **copy**. may i know how to use conditions here in pipeline job?

```
node('') {
stage ('clone'){
    Build job : 'Job1'
  }
stage ('Build'){
parallel(firstTask: {
    stage ('Job2'){
    build job: 'Job2', propagate: true 
    }
}, secondTask: {
    stage ('Job3'){
    build job: 'Job3', propagate: true
    }
})
stage ('copy'){
    build job: 'copy'
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First and foremost you will need to declare stage under stages and not under node. As per default behaviour of pipeline, if a build fails in a stage, it will automatically skip next stages.
2. There are lot of options for using conditions in pipeline. One of the option I often use is `when {}`.
   Here is an example-

```
Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        stage('Example Deploy') {
            when {
                branch 'production'
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more details and options, refer this documentation - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/